# How to make a simple error bar line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to make a chart which shows the 95% confidence interval between my results. I already know the lower and upper bound, and just want a dot which has an error bar leaving that point in each direction. One would be horizontal (to show which factors cross 0) and one would be vertical (to compare population estimates from various models), and I would ideally want to make this in ggplot. From what I have seen ggplot error bars assume that they have to calculate it for you, but I already have the numbers available.

In case it helps, this is how I have my data

```
 Category     lower upper 
1  MaxEntOwn  6988 16105
2 MaxEntMart  2228 10972
3     OccOwn 26324 60667
4    OccMart  8391 41332
```

And this is what I have tried

```
ggplot(PopGraphData, aes(x = Category)) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper))
```

And what I get is this peculiar looking graph:

[image]

I do not even begin to comprehend how the y-axis ended up like that

Comment: Your y-axis variable is obviously not “numeric”. Probably a factor. They are internally represented as integers so all your error bats end exactly at a horizontal grid line. Look at your data with `str`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it this way: To add the point we calculate the mean and plot additional errorbar.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

  df %>% 
    mutate(mean = (lower+upper)/2) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Category)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = mean), size = 3) +  
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2)
```

data

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("MaxEntOwn", "MaxEntMart", "OccOwn", 
"OccMart"), lower = c(6988L, 2228L, 26324L, 8391L), upper = c(16105L, 
10972L, 60667L, 41332L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

[image]